# MD command for directory tree

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am pretty new with the Windows command line and I cant figure out this little problem.

I want to create a directory tree that looks like the following: 
[image: example]

I already tried with command: `MD Opgaven Oplos\Hfst1\Hfst2`

But I cant figure out how to get Hfst1 and Hfst2 in the map Oplos in 1 command.

I want to create this entire directory with 1 command in the Windows command line or PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner:

```
md S\Opgaven,S\Oplos\Hfst1,S\Oplos\Hfst2,S\Windows,S\Taken\Windows,S\Taken\Access
```

Proof that it works:

```
PS> tree s

E:\SCRATCH\S
├───Opgaven
├───Oplos
│   ├───Hfst1
│   └───Hfst2
├───Taken
│   ├───Access
│   └───Windows
└───Windows
```

Answer (score 2):

Copy this into a file named with a BAT or CMD extension.  It is written from the perspective of your "S" folder so place it there and run it to create the rest of the tree.

```
MD Opgaven
MD Oplos
MD Oplos\Hfst1
MD Oplos\Hfst2
MD Windows
MD Taken
MD Taken\Windows
MD Taken\Access
```

If you'd also like it to create the "S" folder as well, use this version:

```
MD S
MD S\Opgaven
MD S\Oplos
MD S\Oplos\Hfst1
MD S\Oplos\Hfst2
MD S\Windows
MD S\Taken
MD S\Taken\Windows
MD S\Taken\Access
```